# Why is there an extra agument passed when i give a function to python customtinker button's command?

Tags: python, customtkinter

```
import customtkinter as ctk
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

class Window(ctk.CTk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title("cinema kiosk system")
    self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.resizable(False, False)

    login_frame = LoginFrame(self)
    login_frame.pack(fill="both",expand=1)

    

class LoginFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)

    self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1,weight=3)

    lbl_welcome = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Welcome. Please Login.")
    lbl_welcome.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2,pady=10)
    lbl_username = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="username:")
    lbl_username.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="E")
    lbl_password = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="password:")
    lbl_password.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="E")
    ent_username = ctk.CTkEntry(self,placeholder_text="username", placeholder_text_color="gray")
    ent_username.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=12,pady=10,sticky="EW")
    ent_password = ctk.CTkEntry(self,placeholder_text="password", placeholder_text_color="gray")
    ent_password.grid(column=1,row=2,padx=12,pady=10,sticky="EW")
    btn_login = ctk.CTkButton(self,text="login",command=lambda: self.check_login(ent_username.get(),ent_password.get()))
    btn_login.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2,pady=10)
    lbl_error = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Login failed. Please try again")
    lbl_error.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2,pady=10)

  def check_login(u,p):
    if u == "user" and p == "bhjs":
      print("login as user")
    elif u == "admin" and p == "pass":
      print("login as admin")
    else:
      print("login failed")

w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

The above code is my attempt to build a login page. I created a button called btn_login and give it the function check_login. When I pressed the button, It gives an error saying there are 3 arguments passed to the function check_login while it only takes two.

```
def check_login(c,u,p):
    print(c)
    print(u)
    print(p)
    if u == "user" and p == "bhjs":
      print("login as user")
    elif u == "admin" and p == "pass":
      print("login as admin")
    else:
      print("login failed")
```

I modified the function to see what arguments are given and the extra argument is ".!loginframe". Why does this happen?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CustomTkinter at all; whenever a method of a class is called, it receives as its first parameter the instance on which it was invoked, which is traditionally named `self`.